# SwiftUI - Setting maxHeight does nothing for Text() inside LazyVGrid()

Tags: text, swiftui, grid

I'm trying to make some buttons in a `LazyVGrid`, but for some reason when I do this, `maxHeight` has no effect:

```
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
    ForEach(0...20, id: \.self) { index in
        Button(action: {
            buttonPressed(char: buttons[index])
        }, label: {
            Text(buttons[index])
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: 80, maxHeight: 80)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(getButtonColour(char: buttons[index])))
        })
    }
}
```

Here are the definitions to variables used in this snippet:

```
private let buttons = [buttons' text is here]
private let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 0, maximum: 80), spacing: 16), count: 4)
```

Outside of a `LazyVGrid`, `.frame(maxWidth: 80, maxHeight: 8)` takes effect and makes the element bigger, but for some reason, here it doesn't.

Any help would be welcome! Thank you.

Comment: Do you expect a 80X80 rectangle?

Comment: I expect a 80x80 square max size, but smaller if there isn't space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the `idealHeight` to `80` as well.

```
Text(buttons[index])
    .font(.system(size: 30))
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .frame(maxWidth: 80, idealHeight: 80, maxHeight: 80) // <- Here
    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(getButtonColour(char: buttons[index]).opacity(Double(index) / Double(buttons.count) + 0.1)))
```

Result (colors may look different because I don't have all the functions):

[image: Result]

---

Additionally, in the screenshot you can see not all the characters are shown. You should change the range in the `ForEach` to `0 ..< buttons.count` to fix this.

Comment: When `idealHeight` and `maxHeight` are the same, it is enough to use `height`.

Comment: @mahan Not sure about that. Consider the following: `VStack { Color.red.frame(idealHeight: 400, maxHeight: 400).frame(height: 400).padding() Color.red.frame(height: 400).frame(idealHeight: 400, maxHeight: 400).padding() }` That's different depending on which you use. (sorry for annoying copy & paste-ability for code in comments)

Comment: It is exactly the same. Try this,       VStack {
            Color.red
                .frame(idealHeight: 40, maxHeight: 40)
//                .frame(height: 40)
                .padding()
            Color.red
//                .frame(height: 40)
                .frame(idealHeight: 40, maxHeight: 40)
                .padding()
            
        }

Comment: @mahan It's the same until the sum of the heights are too tall for the screen, which is why I assume they used `maxHeight` in the original question. Using `idealHeight` & `maxHeight` vs just `height` will depend on their situation. Otherwise if the text is too long it will go off screen if using a fixed height, but that may or may not be what they are looking for

Comment: @George_E, the problem with that is, when a screen is too small to accomodate all the buttons, it doesn't make them any smaller.